# How to do Django-models-like metaclass trick

Tags: python, django, orm, metaclass

I'm making Django like ORM for my study project and because we are not allowed to use existing ORMs (If you want to use one you have to code it yourself) and just for educating myself, i thought that the same kind of ORM like in Django would be nice.

In the ORM I wan't to make model definitions in same style that they are implemented in Django. ie.

```
class Person(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
```

Django uses metaclasses and in my project I'm  using too, but I have problem with the fact that metaclasses construct *classes* not instances and so all attributes are class attributes and shared between all instances.

This is generic example what I tried but because of what I earlier said, it won't work:

```
def getmethod(attrname):
    def _getmethod(self):
        return getattr(self, "__"+attrname).get()
    return _getmethod

def setmethod(attrname):
    def _setmethod(self, value):
        return getattr(self, "__"+attrname).set(value)
    return _setmethod

class Metaclass(type):
    def __new__(cls, name, based, attrs):
        ndict = {}
        for attr in attrs:
            if isinstance(attrs[attr], Field):
                ndict['__'+attr] = attrs[attr]
                ndict[attr] = property(getmethod(attr), setmethod(attr))
        return super(Metaclass, cls).__new__(cls, name, based, ndict)


class Field:
    def __init__(self):
        self.value = 0;

    def set(self, value):
        self.value = value

    def get(self):
        return self.value

class Mainclass:
    __metaclass__ = Metaclass

class Childclass(Mainclass):
    attr1 = Field()
    attr2 = Field()


a = Childclass()
print "a, should be 0:", a.attr1
a.attr1 = "test"
print "a, should be test:", a.attr1

b = Childclass()

print "b, should be 0:", b.attr1
```

I tried to lookup from Djangos source but it is too complicated for me to understand and the "magic" seems to be hidden somewhere.

Question is simple, how Django does this in very simplificated example?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The answer is quite simple really, once you check the right code. The metaclass used by Django adds all fields to `<model>._meta.fields` (well, kinda), but the field attribute is removed from the actual class. The only exception to this is a `RelatedField` subclass, in which case an object descriptor is added (similar to a property - in fact, a propery is  an object descriptor, just with a native implementation).

Then, in the `__init__` method of the model, the code iterates over all fields, and either sets the provided value in `*args` or `**kwargs`, or sets a default value *on the instance*.

In your example, this means that the class `Person` will never have attributes named `first_name` and `last_name`, but both fields are stored in `Person._meta.fields`. However, an instance of `Person` will always have attributes named `first_name` and `last_name`, even if they are not provided as arguments.